# Convert time object of cakephp 3 in Y-m-d format

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working in cakephp 3 and I want to print my time object in Y-m-d format.

This is my object

```
'expiry' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {
        'time' => '2015-07-31T00:00:00+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false
},
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: I want to print it in Y-m-d format

Comment: I asked for a problem, not a requirement

Comment: I am not able to it. I'm getting a `Unknown or bad timezone (7/31/15 12:00 AM) InvalidArgumentException` when using `$users->expiry->format('Y-m-d')`.

Comment: I haven't seen that PHP code anywhere. What does the call to `object` do @CodeZilla?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Cakephp 3.* you use the `Time::i18nFormat()` method. It worked for me

```
  $customformat = $date->i18nFormat('YYY-MM-dd');
```

Edit:

I looked through the **3.3** docs and found this good example. There are constants you can use to format dates for common use cases like `Time::UNIX_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`,`\IntlDateFormatter::FULL`

```
$time = new Time('2014-04-20 22:10');
$time->i18nFormat(); // outputs '4/20/14, 10:10 PM' for the en-US locale
$time->i18nFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::FULL); // Use the full date and time format
$time->i18nFormat([\IntlDateFormatter::FULL, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT]); // Use full date but short time format
$time->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); // outputs '2014-04-20 22:10'
$time->i18nFormat(Time::UNIX_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT); // outputs '1398031800'
```

[CakePHP documentation](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.I18n.Date.html)

Edit 2:

Also look at the [time helper class](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.Helper.TimeHelper.html)

You can reference it in views like so:

`$this->Time->format($format);`

Comment: CakePHP doesn't have the best documentation out there. Some things you can only find out by looking at the code

Answer (score 4):

`$object->created->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: tried it. getting `Unknown or bad timezone (7/31/15 12:00 AM) InvalidArgumentException` error.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. All I had to do was use the Time helper in my view.
`$this->Time->format($user->expiry,'Y-M-d')`.

Answer (score 0):

get result where dt_updated is less than current date.

```
$result = $this->ModelTable->find('all');
$result->where(['DATE(dt_updated) <'=>date('Y-m-d')]);
```