# Changing default datetime format in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cake Crud Api plugin and baking all models.

The datetime format in the json response is like this:

```
"created": "2016-08-01T08:49:11+0000"
```

I want it to look like a normal datatime:

```
"created": "2016-08-01 08:49:11"
```

I have tryied setting application wide:

```
Time::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

with no luck and also I have searched for any Time reference in the Crud plugin, but I haven't finded out where the default ajax format comes from.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452882/convert-time-object-of-cakephp-3-in-y-m-d-format

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (x.x.x)! There have been quite some changes with regards to datetime stuff since the initial release of CakePHP 3. Also, are you using immutable date/time objects ([**check your bootstrap**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.6/config/bootstrap.php#L217))?

Comment: @ndm I am using inmutable date/time and my CakePHP version is ~3.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someone has the same problem just add this to your app controller:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    Time::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');  // For any mutable DateTime
    FrozenTime::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');  // For any immutable DateTime
    Date::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');  // For any mutable Date
    FrozenDate::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');  // For any immutable Date

}
```