# Cakephp 3 giving date and time fields in frozentime object

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.2

I am using cakephp 3.2 and when i am retrieving data by find query it is giving date fields in this format

```
Array
(
[0] => Cake\I18n\FrozenDate Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-08-01 00:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )
)
```

and time fields in frozentime

```
Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
(
 [date] => 2016-10-11 10:00:00
 [timezone_type] => 3
 [timezone] => UTC
)
```

I need a common setting or global solution for complete site. So when i fetch the data by find query from database it should give me date time in simple format without any frozendate object.

like this

```
Array(
 [0] => 2016-08-01
)
```

Comment: None of the answers to date seem to meet the OP's request that "I need a **common setting or global solution** ... so when i fetch the data ... it should give me date time in simple format without any frozendate object." Current answers require code changes everywhere the date is used.

Comment: @MM. Maybe [ndm's answer for "Cakephp 3.2 change default date format"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35677192/) is of help?

Comment: Related: [Convert time object of cakephp 3 in Y-m-d format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31452882/) and [CakePHP 3 Date format Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51167620/)

Answer (score 8):

Simply call `->format('Y-m-d')` on your `Cake\I18n\FrozenDate` object.

There's no need for `Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat()` or `$this->Time->format()`

Comment: Would like to add that `Cake\I18n\FrozenTime` is a valid argument to [`\Datetime::diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) as well.

Answer (score 4):

In boostrap.php add

```
Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

still it comes with forzenDate object with same params But when you will print in view then it will print the proper format

```
echo $var->created;  // print: 2016-08-01
```

Reference for Dates [Datetime Format Syntax](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax)

Comment: @Irshad Khan Thank you for adding the Datetime Format syntax link to this answer. I was looking for what date syntax it follows to fix my code. I wouldn't know it doesn't follow the regular PHP syntax formats if it weren't for your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **TimeHelper** for formating **datetime** in **View**

**Example**

```
echo $this->Time->format(
  $YourDateTimeVariable, #Your datetime variable
  'Y-MM-d'               #Your custom datetime format
);
```

CakePHP `TimeHelper` function details is [Here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/time.html#using-the-helper)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly print the date object in any custom date format by using inbuilt  **i18nFormat** function.

```
$frozenDateObj->i18nFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

Use [datetime-syntax](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#date-field-symbol-table) reference for more customization