# CakePHP 3 Date format Issue

Tags: date, cakephp-3.2

I researched everywhere but could not find the solution, 
In the database, I am using `from_date` field as `date`(2018-07-07) type
But when I find the data then it auto converts in from_date to 'Cake\I18n\Date Object'

```
[from_date] => Cake\I18n\Date Object
        (
            [time] => 2018-07-07T00:00:00+00:00
            [timezone] => UTC
            [fixedNowTime] => 
        )
```

I what this as

```
[from_date] => '2018-07-07'
```

I know we can covert this by

```
$obj->from_date->format('Y-M-D');
```

but the data is coming in an array of 10000 loops, this is not a good idea to convert in the loop.
I also tried this in bootstrap.php

```
Type::build('date')->useLocaleParser()->setLocaleFormat('y-m-d');
```

but this is also not working.

Please help

Comment: there are many ways, but what is the reason you want to format the date?

Comment: I am converting this in JSON format & this format creating an issue in javascript. in JSON format, it shows 2018-07-07T00:00:00+00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `bootstrap.php` you can set the default format you want when converting `Date` and  `FrozenDate` to string in Json

see the manual [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#formatting) and the api [**here**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.I18n.FrozenTime.html#_setJsonEncodeFormat)

note that you have to use string patterns described [**here**](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details) and not the patterns you usually use with `date()`

so your code should be

```
\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); 
\Cake\I18n\Date::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: You'd probably want to apply this on `\Cake\I18n\Date`/`\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate` instead. Also use `yyyy`, as `YYYY` represents the week-numbering year, which isn't always the same as the calendar year.

Comment: i tried this \Cake\I18n\Date::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');  now working,